# How do I get the current position of my map? (leaflet.js)

Tags: jquery, dictionary, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet.js and on a user interaction (which happens outside of the map div), I want to get the current position (lat, lng, zoom).

I could find zoom, but the field _lastCenter doesn't get me the actual position, instead I get the coordinates from the map initialisation.

How can I get the current coordinates?

```js
this.getZoom = function () { return map._zoom }
this.getLat = function () { return map._lastCenter.lat }
this.getLon = function () { return map._lastCenter.lng  }
```

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-getcenter

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for :)